How to use codeclimate image directly from gitlab ci/cd to scan code?
What I would like to achieve:
Run CodeClimate as part of GitLab CI/CD without having to go through the whole docker Docker-in-Docker + Docker image pull setup (since this has performance drawbacks).
What did I try:
Using this code:
codeclimateworking:
  image: docker:stable
 script:
    - docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate:latest
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD" --volume "$PWD":/code --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc codeclimate/codeclimate:latest analyze -f json > gl2-code-quality-report.json || true
     services:
    - docker:dind
  artifacts:
    paths: [ gl2-code-quality-report.json ]
    reports:
      codequality: gl2-code-quality-report.json

Above is working however, it has some drawbacks, as it requires to first pull docker itself, then using the docker in docker approach, invoke codeclimate.
I hope to achieve the same result by using the image itself directly, like this:
codequalitybad:
  image:
    name: codeclimate/codeclimate:latest
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'Code Quality Report'
    paths: [ "gl1-code-quality-report.json" ]
    reports:
      codequality: gl1-code-quality-report.json
  script:
  - ??? What to add here?

For the script part, I tried adding something like: analyze -f json > gl1-code-quality-report.json || true. But this is not working.
Is there a way to add something in the script section, so there is no need to pull the docker:stable image first, but execute a scan directly?
